Question from Taubes' SW$\Rightarrow$ Gr
I am trying to understand Taubes' paper on SW$\Rightarrow$ Gr. I don't understand how either of the equations 2.16 or 2.17 appears, I would be happy to understand how the curvature term $F_a$ appears in equation 2.17.


You have to just show your work to see where you get stuck. I don't have any saved computation from back in the day when I was going thru all this, but I believe it's arising from the $\beta\nabla_A'\beta^\ast$ term in 2.16, once you take derivatives, since (as pointed out on the line after 2.17 not shown here) $\kappa+F_A$ is the curvature of $\nabla_A'$ (and note that the RHS of 2.17 has the term $(\kappa+F_A)\beta^*\beta$).

@ChrisGerig Heuristically it seems plausible that $F_a$ appears since we are kind of differentiating twice for both $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta |^2$. My problem is I don't see an easy way to see that exactly $F_a(|\alpha|^2+|\beta |^2)$ appears given that $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta |^2$ has opposite signs before, I guess the details are hidden in Hodge star $*$ of $d^*d$.

The LHS of 2.16 is a typo, remove $d^*$.
